# SQL 2000 - Execute process task - doesn't run exe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, dts

I am currently developing completely on a local machine and have a DTS package that on completion should run a local exe file that compresses the csv files that were just imported.

If I run the package in the designer or from the list of packages then all is fine and the files are compressed.

If I run the file from SQL Agent as a scheduled task or manually start the task then the DTS runs fine and completes successfully but the files are not compressed.

I also tried pointing the step at a basic bat file that deletes the csv files. This doesn't run either.

I don't think there are any network access issues as everything is running from local disks and the data is imported from the same directory as where I want to run the exe.

I have tried running my SQLSERVERAGENT service as .\Administrator and also as Local Service Account without success.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

That job will run your dts package with it's credentials. Have you checked the folder properties to ensure .\Administrator or Local service account has access to that folder?